# Track and identify users with Memcached

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, memcached

I have social network website that contains thousands of users.
Until now I used the classic way of storing user's details in the session object.
Now, I want to upgrade it, so it will work against Memcached, and the key value is the "userId".

My question is:
What is or where is the best place to keep the "userId" so I can use it constantly for querying the user's details from Memcached?

Answer (score 1):

Three options as I see it:

1. Store it in the `ViewState[]` collection on your pages
2. Store it in a cookie
3. Store it in all urls

these can also be combined for added security/robustness.

Best practice imo would be to combine cookie with viewstate.

Comment: Either your store it on the server or on the client, or both. What's wrong with adding it to the ViewState[]? Create a base page or HttpModule which handles setting the id.